# How do I loop through certain mappings of a dict?

Tags: python, class, for-loop, dictionary

So what I am trying to do is loop only through certain mappings of a dict. So for example, for any key that has a space in it, print("I have a space"). For any key that do not include a space in the name, print("I do not have a space").

To be more specific, the file I am trying to do this on can found [here](https://github.com/IneffableBunch/Classroom-Pummel/blob/master/Classroom%20Pummel/engine.py) starting line 262

Absolutely any constructive critisism and/or suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

EDIT: Nevermind, Python was having a stubborn compilation error that was not showing in PowerShell. Thanks for all the answers though!

Comment: @cdarke I've tried all the basic examples, including the answers given below. (Do to comments I can't give you an example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like this:

```
for key in mydict:
    if ' ' in key:
        print 'I have a space'
    else:
        print 'I don\'t have a space'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a for loop.

```
for key in dictionary:
    if ' ' in key:
        #perform logic here
        print('I have a space')
    else:
        print('I do not have a space')
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.